# Download an image on a particular url and return error if the image does not exist PHP

Tags: php, image, download

I am trying to download an image if it exists on a url and if it does not exists it should return an error.

So far i have tried this

```js
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    $fp = fopen('images/'.$isbn.'.jpg', 'wb');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    // don't download content
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if(curl_exec($ch)!==FALSE){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
```

Now it does return `0` when the image does not exists but a corrupted image file still gets created .

Now i am not really sure if i should `getimagesize` to check if the image exists and then call my curl function .

```js
if(@getimagesize($remoteImageURL)){
    //image exists!
}
```

Also please note that i will run my script on 14 million records , so optimization is crucial.

```js
This URL returns an image

https://pictures.abebooks.com/isbn/9780007428540-uk.jpg

This URL returns an xml error

https://pictures.abebooks.com/isbn/9781781108765-uk.jpg
```

EDIT 1:

```js
$ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 $content  = curl_exec($ch);
 $contentType = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
 curl_close($ch);
 if($contentType=='image/jpeg'){
  //download image
 }else{
  //return error;
 }
```

Is the above code the right approach?

Comment: `CURLOPT_FILE` is created the moment you call `fopen()`. Using this technique, you can't prevent the file from being created if the URL does not exist, but you could `unlink()` it before returning `0`

Comment: but don't you think using unlink is somewhat of a hack

Comment: Also, in terms of optimisation, you'll want to `fclose()` your file handle at some point

Comment: Well, yes. Personally, I wouldn't use `CURLOPT_FILE` at all, but write the result of `curl_exec()` into a file if there wasn't an error.

Comment: ok .. i'll just quickly try it out

Comment: @rickdenhaan i have updated my question , could you please check it out

Comment: That's how I would do it, yes.

Comment: but when i use `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);` it returns image data too in encrypted format

Comment: something like this ����JFIF��C    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222���I"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br�

Comment: now i cannot understand why it's happening since i am not returning any data myself

Comment: That's not encrypted, that is what binary JPEG image data looks like. It shouldn't do that though. I have no explanation why you're getting that from `curl_getinfo`

Comment: alright , thanks . i'll just search it out on why it's happening